# Yii2 DropDownList добавить атрибут "title" к полю option

Tags: yii2, select, select2, dropdown, атрибуты

Всем привет. Нужно отрисовать поле title в option(select). При том, что у меня $remittances_title является массивом. Как можно разгребсти? Пример кода ниже. Подскажите где туплю, кто знает. Спасибо

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'remittanceInformationType', [
                'inputOptions' => [
                    'name' => 'remittanceInformationType',
                    'id' => 'selectRemittanceInfo',
                    'data-placeholder' => 'Выберите назначение платежа',
                ],
                'template' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">{input}</div></div>'
            ])->dropDownList($remittances_type, [
                    'prompt' => '',
                    'title' => $remittances_title,
            ]); ?>
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вам нужно. Что именно у вас в `$remittances_type` и что в `$remittances_title`? И как должен выглядеть select?

Comment: если я правильно понимаю, то вам нужно использовать не `title` а `options` -- так можно задать кастомные атрибуты для каждого тега `option` http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#activeDropDownList()-detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$remittances_type = [0 => 'val1', 1 => 'val2', 5 => 'val5'];
$remittances_title = [0 => 'Опция 1', 1 => 'Опция 2', 5 => 'Опция 5'];

echo $form->field($model, 'remittanceInformationType', [
    'inputOptions' => [
        'name' => 'remittanceInformationType',
        'id' => 'selectRemittanceInfo',
        'data-placeholder' => 'Выберите назначение платежа',
    ],
    'template' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">{input}</div></div>'
])->dropDownList($remittances_type, [
    'prompt' => '',
    'options' => array_map(function ($v) {
        return ['title' => $v];
    }, $remittances_title)
]);
```